# Waiting for Input without Interrupting with Loops

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

First of all, I use windows so i couldn't make curses work in windows.
I'm trying to make a login interface while an ASCII Animation is Looping.

```
def animation():
    while True:
        #something that do animation

def login_screen():
    uname = str(input("Username : "))
    passw = str(input("Password : "))
    print("Welcome {}".format(uname))
```

so how do i do this in one console screen ? this is for example :
[image: What i want to do]

Comment: You're going to have to use curses, or the more complicated ANSI escape codes and other mechanisms that curses uses.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is that mean that i need to use Unix-based System ?

Comment: Many different consoles support ANSI codes. You'll need to look up compatibility for your console. I'm pretty sure the Windows console has some support for them.

Comment: Try this [curses](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) module. Despite what it says, I think the Python 3 version does support Unicode. Also, the console in Windows 10 supports virtual terminal sequences (i.e. VT100 / ANSI) if you prefer, but that's no help for older Windows versions.

Comment: It's going to be a challenge to update the animation text while performing blocking I/O input.

Comment: @selbie how about threading or multiprocessing ?

Comment: @Wowotek - quite possibly.